# hive dynamic partitioning error: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying static and dynamic partitioning in hive. Static partitioning works well but dynamic partitioning fails with the following error:

```
Query ID = administrator_20190609215311_a645f498-febf-41f7-9134-70300e0aaa3b
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
2019-06-09 21:53:12,244 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_local174838902_0002 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

I am not sure why it is getting failed. Has anyone faced the same issue ? Could anyone let me know how do I resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: The question is of very poor quality: No job tracker logs provided, no query, no configuration. Please improve it

Comment: Can you post job logs, HS2 logs for beeline, hive log for hive CLI to check more on this

Comment: please tell me where do I find hive error logs. The /var/log/hive directory doesn't exist and I am new to hive and hadoop.